# "Fable should be taught as fable..." Is this quote from Hypatia a fake?

Tags: quotes

The following quote, attributed to [Hypatia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypatia) (~360-415 AD), is found in [many sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fable%20should%20be%20taught%20as%20fable%22%20-inurl%3Askeptics):

> Fable should be taught as fable, myth as myth, and miracles as poetic
> fancies. To teach superstitions as truth is horrifying. The mind of a
> child accepts them and only through great pain, perhaps tragedy, can
> the child be relieved of them. Men will fight for superstition as
> quickly as for the living truth -- even more so, since a superstition
> is intangible, you can't get at it to refute it, but truth is a point
> of view, as so is changeable.

I wonder if these words can reasonably attributed to Hypatia, or, elsewhere, in case this a misattribution, if the source can be traced.

Comment: Wikipedia says "No written work widely recognized by scholars as Hypatia's own has survived to the present time", and other educational articles I found say the same. So at best, this might turn out to be a quote attributed to her by a contemporary source.

Comment: @NateEldredge My original question (before the editing) asked, not if she had "written" that, but whether if the quote was authentic, perhaps in some weaker sense - and, in any case, I was interested in the source of the attribution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fact that this so-called quotation appears in exactly the same ENGLISH wording in hundreds of google entries, all without any indication of its source, ought to raise the alarm. In fact, it comes from a book published in 1908, a fanciful “biography” of Hypatia in volume 10 of “Little Journeys” by Elbert Hubbard, again without any source. There does not seem to be any trace of it before Hubbard, who evidently invented it.

You can find Hubbard’s chapter here: http://www.online-literature.com/elbert-hubbard/journeys-vol-ten/10/
There is nice hatchet job here: http://bedejournal.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/encyclopaedia-britannica-hits-rock.html